# Project Euler 23 in Scala (non-abundant sums)

Tags: performance, programming-challenge, functional-programming, scala, mathematics

I recently overhauled my solution to [Project Euler Problem 23](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23) (which asks for the sum of all positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers) to move it from an imperative style to a functional style and tried to increase its speed. However, the performance is still slow. I have clocked this solution at 58 seconds, and the older imperative solution at 64 seconds.

I am mainly hoping for feedback on how I could speed up the performance of this solution. The bottleneck appears to be at the `notSumAbundant` function. Is there a reliable way to reduce the number of values I need to check? Can this portion of `notSumAbundant` be made faster in any other way?

```
if(!abundantList.exists(x => abundantList.contains(num - x))) { 
  notSumAbundant(num + 1, num :: currentList) }
```

I am also hoping for feedback if my code falls short of functional programming best practices.

```
val t0 = System.nanoTime()

//function to find factors
def factors(num: Int) = {
    val max = (num / 2) + 1
    val factors = for(i <- 1 to max if num % i == 0) yield { i }
    factors
}

//function to find sums
def sumList(numList: IndexedSeq[Int]) = {
  val sum = numList.reduceLeft( _ + _ )
  sum
}

//function to recursively form list of abundant numbers
def abundance(num: Int, currentList: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  if(num <= 20161){
  val numFactors = factors(num)
  val factorSum = sumList(numFactors)

  //if the number is abundant, prepend it to the running list of abundant numbers in the function call
  if(factorSum > num) { abundance(num + 1, num :: currentList) }
  else { abundance(num + 1, currentList) }
  } else return currentList
}

//all abundant numbers
val abundant = abundance(3, List())

//function to create a list of numbers which cannot be formed as the sum of two abundant numbers
def notSumAbundant(num: Int, currentList: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  val abundantList = abundant.filter(_ < num)
  if(num <= 20161) { 
    //if it cannot be made as the sum of abundant numbers, prepend it to the current list when calling on the next number
    if(!abundantList.exists(x => abundantList.contains(num - x))) { 
      notSumAbundant(num + 1, num :: currentList) 
      } else { notSumAbundant(num + 1, currentList) }
 }  else return currentList
}

//store the values and then sum them
val answerList = notSumAbundant(1, List())
val answer = answerList.reduceLeft(_ + _)

val t1 = System.nanoTime()
println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) / 1000000000 + " seconds")
println(answer)
```

Update:

Changing the `nonAbundantSum` function to use a `Set` instead of a `List` worked to get this down to 2 seconds, as t. fochtman suggested:

```
val abundant = abundance(3, List()).toSet
//function to create a list of numbers which cannot be formed as the sum of two abundant numbers
def notSumAbundant(num: Int, currentSet: Set[Int]): List[Int] = {
  val abundantList = abundant.filter(_ < num)
  if(num <= 20161) { 
    //if it cannot be made as the sum of abundant numbers, prepend it to the current list when calling on the next number
    if(!abundantList.exists(x => abundantList.contains(num - x))) { 
      val updatedSet = (num :: currentSet.toList).toSet
      notSumAbundant(num + 1, updatedSet) 
      } else { notSumAbundant(num + 1, currentSet) }
 }  else return currentSet.toList
}

//store the values and then sum them
val answerList = notSumAbundant(1, Set())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reduce the run time of your code to a few seconds (2 seconds on my computer) by changing the type of `abundant` from a `List` to an immutable `Set`.

You were correct that `!abundantList.exists(x => abundantList.contains(num - x))` was the major bottleneck in your code.

This is a bottleneck because checking that an item exists in a `List` means inspecting every item in the `List` until we find it or reach the end of the `List`. Fortunately we can use a `Set` (which under the hood is supported by the `immutable.HashMap` class) and reduce the search time for objects from linear to effectively constant.

Notice that in the code below I simply applied the method `toSet` to your `abundance` function converting the returned `List` to a `Set`.

```
val abundant = abundance(3, List()).toSet

def notSumAbundant(num: Int, currentList: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  if(num <= n) {
    val abundantSet: Set[Int] = abundant.filter(_ < num)
    if (!abundantSet.exists(x => abundantSet.contains(num - x))) {
      notSumAbundant(num + 1, num :: currentList)
    } else
      notSumAbundant(num + 1, currentList)
  } else
    currentList
}
```

For more information check out [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html) nice write up on Scala collections that is co-written by the creator of Scala, Martin Odersky.